# Unhandled promise rejection (id:0) Error: database or disk is full....

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[This is the error that i'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OxQX.jpg)

I'm trying to pass data input in JSON format with async storage and receive data with getItem.

```js
 async componentWillMount() {
    try {
    let vehiclesAlldata = await AsyncStorage.getItem('vehiclesData')
      let vehicleData= JSON.parse(vehiclesAlldata)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    }
```

Whenever i try to get input data it shows null and throw this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"database or disk is full"_ seems pretty self-explanatory?

Comment: can u please elaborate which database or disk it is referring  to?

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncStorage`, at least on Android, imposes a maximum database size of about 6MB (from what I can find using Google, I'm not a React Native developer myself).

I also found that you can increase this maximum [here](https://github.com/ptmt/using-async-storage-in-react-native/blob/master/Readme.md#database-or-disk-is-full):

```
long size = 50L * 1024L * 1024L; // 50 MB

com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier
  .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
  .setMaximumSize(size);
```

More info [in this article](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/4/Increase-Android-AsyncStorage-Size-in-React-Native).

Comment: can u please tell me where should i put this code to go to maximum asyncstorage database size @robertklep

Comment: A bit late for you Kazi, but for others who trip over this page when faced with the same issue, look under `android/app/src/main/java/` for a file named MainApplicaton.java, and read the "More info in this Article" link from Robert

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Unfortunately, i'm working on a bare expo workflow.